# divides a number equally by a percentage

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a initial number, lets say 3700, and want to divide it equally by a percentage. I have this code:

```js
let available = 3700, percent = 10

for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    let use = index == 0 ? (percent / 100) * available : available / ((percent - index) % percent)

    console.log(`Index: ${index} | Use > ${use}`)

    console.log(`Before reduction > ${available}`)
    available -= use
    console.log(`After reduction > ${available}\n`)
}
```

```js
Index: 0 | Use > 370
Before deduction > 3700
After deduction > 3330 

Index: 1 | Use > 370   
Before deduction > 3330
After deduction > 2960 

...

Index: 9 | Use > 370
Before deduction > 370
After deduction > 0
```

Its works dividing equally by 10%, however any other percentage number shows unexpected results.

Any help?

**Edit: Example using percent=5**

```js
let available = 3700, percent = 5

for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    let use = index == 0 ? (percent / 100) * available : available / ((percent - index) % percent)

    console.log(`Index: ${index} | Use > ${use}`)

    console.log(`Before deduction > ${available}`)
    available -= use
    console.log(`After deduction > ${available}\n`)
}
```

```js
Index: 0 | Use > 185
Before deduction > 3700
After deduction > 3515

Index: 1 | Use > 878.75
Before deduction > 3515
After deduction > 2636.25

...

Index: 9 | Use > NaN
Before deduction > NaN
After deduction > NaN
```

Expected behavior:

```js
Index: 0 | Use > 185
Before deduction > 3700
After deduction > 3515

Index: 1 | Use > 185
Before deduction > 3515
After deduction > 3330

...

Index: 9 | Use > 185
Before deduction > 2035
After deduction > 1850
```

Comment: What's the unexpected behavior for your case?

Comment: And what is the *expected* behaviour? Why do you have `(percent - index) % percent` - what are you meant to calculate here?

Comment: ^ Definitely have to agree with that question too. Are you trying to deduct until available = 0 or deduct 10 times?

Comment: @Andrew deduct until 0

Comment: So, after 10 deductions, the result should be zero. Is that with *any* percentage? What is it a percentage *of*?

Comment: @VLAZ added a example using a percent of 5

Comment: No problem if my number is not zero at the final, i just need to equally divide it by a fixed percentage

Comment: @c0nf1ck I'm still not sure what you need here. Why is this code in a loop? Surely if the percentage is supposed to be over the base, you just need to calculate `available * (percent / 100)` only once, not every iteration in the loop. Also, if you what is the loop for? You can similarly just calculate how much you get in the end by doing `available - (loopCounter * (percent / 100))`. If you need to find out *how many* portions something divides in, then it's going to be `100 / percent`. Assuming `percent` is a divisor of `100` otherwise you'd need to round.

Comment: @VLAZ the loop is just a example, my original code is not in a loop. Its a trade system where i need to divide a available capital equally based in a percentage to enter in a trade. In this example i just want to show 10 opened trades (loop with 10 interactions) using 10% of a capital available. But 10 open trade using only 5% gives me unexpected results, understand?

Comment: btw i have the **opened positions**, which is, in this example, represented by the **index** in the loop.

Comment: @Andrew its already in the original post, using 5% and the expected behavior too

Comment: I edited my answer. That should work based on what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important change: revised the ternary operation and changed loop test

See working code below:

```
let available = 3700, percent = 20

for (let index = 0; index < 100/percent; index++) {
    let use = index == 0 ? (percent / 100) * available : available / (100/percent - index)

    console.log(`Index: ${index} | Use > ${use}`)

    console.log(`Before reduction > ${available}`)
    available -= use
    console.log(`After reduction > ${available}\n`)
}
```

Comment: Works with 20%, however not with 5% :/

Comment: It is working now. Check again. I remove the %percent from the ternary

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the conditional when defining use. This should fix it.

```
let available = 3700, percent = 10
let availableBeginning = available

for (let index = 0; available > 0 ; index++) {
    let use = percent / 100) * availableBeginning

     console.log(`Index: ${index} | Use > ${use}`)

     console.log(`Before reduction > ${available}`)
     available -= use
     console.log(`After reduction > ${available}\n`)
}
```

Comment: This is using percentage of a percentage. Didn't work for me.

Comment: You just have to save the original value of available to continue making percentages of.

Comment: I can't save the initial value because this number is dynamic.

Comment: Check the answer. It just copy the original value to a new variable

Comment: Check this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64977736/divides-a-number-equally-by-a-percentage#comment114877243_64977736

Answer (score 0):

This will work for your case. I'm not sure why you have `available / ((percent - index) % percent)), what this is going to do is essentially just divide your original number by your percentage you want to deduct after taking the modulo of that and the original percent. So in this case, after 0 you have the behavior where use = 878.75 because you're dividing 3515 by (5 - 1) % 5 which = 4. 3515 / 4 = 878.85. This is going to deduct rather fast as you're taking at the very least 1 / percent value as an integer of your already deducted number each iteration.

It turns out that your logic for use actually is pointless, if you want to deduct an even amount each time per iteration, you don't have to set it based on any logic...just calculate and deduct repeatedly however many times you want.

Anyway, here's the solution:

```
let available = 3700, percent = 5;
// This is going to be the constant deduction you will continue to use
let deduction = 3700 * (percent / 100);

for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    console.log(`Index: ${index} | Use > ${deduction}`)

    console.log(`Before deduction > ${available}`)
    available -= deduction
    console.log(`After deduction > ${available}\n`)
}
```

Comment: No problem if my number is not zero at the final, i just need to equally divide it by a fixed percentage. I added a example using a percentage of 5%

Comment: Didn't you mention you want it to go to zero, or basically, until it cannot deduct anymore? This will work for that case.

Comment: check this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64977736/divides-a-number-equally-by-a-percentage#comment114877243_64977736